# Converting a population on a grid to coordinates, and vice versa

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

For an ecology project, I need to switch back and forth between two representations of a population on a square grid world:

**Representation 1:** Simply the grid (a 2d Numpy array), where the value in each cell corresponds to the number of individuals in this cell. For instance, with a 3x3 grid:

```
grid = np.array(
    [[0, 1, 0],
     [0, 3, 1],
     [0, 0, 0]]
)
```

**Representation 2:** A 2d Numpy array with the x,y coordinates of each individual on the grid:

```
coords = np.array(
    [[0, 1],
     [1, 1],
     [1, 1],
     [1, 1],
     [1, 2]]
)
```

As you can see, when a cell has more than 1 individual on it, its coordinates repeat. Therefore, `coords` has shape (population_size, 2).

The current implementations for `grid_to_coords()` and `coords_to_grid()` both involve for loops, as you can see below, which slow down the execution considerably:

```
def grid_to_coords(grid):
    non_zero_pos = np.nonzero(grid)
    pop_size = grid.sum(keepdims=False)
    coords = np.zeros((int(pop_size), 2))
    offset = 0
    for i in range(len(non_zero_pos[0])):
        n_in_pos = int(grid[non_zero_pos[0][i], non_zero_pos[1][i]])
        for j in range(n_in_pos):
            coords[i + j + offset] = [non_zero_pos[0][i], non_zero_pos[1][i]]
        offset += j
    return pos

def coords_to_grid(coords, grid_dim):
    grid = np.zeros((grid_dim, grid_dim), dtype=np.int32)
    for x, y in coords:
        # Add a particle to the grid, making sure it is actually on the grid!
        x = max(0, min(x, grid_dim - 1))
        y = max(0, min(y, grid_dim - 1))
        grid[x, y] += 1
    return grid
```

I would need a way to vectorise these two functions. Could you please help?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

grid = np.array(
    [[0, 1, 0],
     [0, 3, 1],
     [0, 0, 0]]
)

coords = np.array(
    [[0, 1],
     [1, 1],
     [1, 1],
     [1, 1],
     [1, 2]]
)


def grid_to_coords(grid):
    """
    >>> grid_to_coords(grid)
    array([[0, 1],
           [1, 1],
           [1, 1],
           [1, 1],
           [1, 2]])
    """
    x, y = np.nonzero(grid) # x = [0 1 1]; y = [1 1 2]
    # np.c_[x, y] = [[0 1]
    #                [1 1]
    #                [1 2]]
    # grid[x, y] = [1 3 1]
    return np.c_[x, y].repeat(grid[x, y], axis=0)


def coords_to_grid(coords, grid_dim):
    """
    >>> coords_to_grid(coords, 3)
    array([[0, 1, 0],
           [0, 3, 1],
           [0, 0, 0]])
    """
    unique, counts = np.unique(coords, axis=0, return_counts=True)
    # unique = [[0 1]
    #           [1 1]
    #           [1 2]]
    # counts = [1 3 1]
    ret = np.zeros((grid_dim, grid_dim), dtype=int)
    ret[unique[:, 0], unique[:, 1]] = counts
    return ret
```

Comment: This is awesome, thanks a lot. Just for the sake of completeness, I'll mention a small change I made to handle the edges of the grid: I inserted the following line in coords_to_grid(), just after the call to np.unique():

**unique = np.clip(unique, 0, grid_dim - 1)**